# Wordpress Password Protected Page is not protected

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

I have a wordpress site with Kalium Theme, I have a page there which needs to be password protected. I have made several pages password protected previously with the same configuration but now a page in my website is not password protected even after making it password protected. On the WP admin panel it is showing that the page is password protected and password is set there as well. I have googled but couldn't find out any solution. Please help me to get rid of this problem and suggest me somthing which can help me to get my page password protected.

Comment: Have you tried it in an incognito window, or when logged out? I'd bet admins are exempt from the password check.

Comment: Yes I have checked in incognito, and even on different system. Don't know why it is not working even after setting it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure about your specific theme but by default when you select password protected, it only hides the content. i.e. the_content(). Therefore, if you wanted to password protect the whole page, update you php to something similiar to the below:

```
<?php

global $post;
get_header();

if ( post_password_required( $post ) ) {
      // Password protecte content.
}else{
    // Page isn't password-protected, show password prompt
    echo get_the_password_form( $post );
}

?>
```

Comment: I know about it, I just want to protect content only, but my content is not password protected even after setting it password protected. I don't know what is wrong with the default behaviour of it.

Comment: I suggested enabling DEBUG LOG and seeing whether there is any further info available: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029327771-Enabling-the-WordPress-Debug-log